# What is the flaw in this logic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

### I have never taken set theory (so go easy on me), I know only what I have read.

Firstly, is there a problem with this statement?

If there exist sets A and B, such that:
|A| = |B|, then

|(A\B) + (A⋂B)| = |(B\A) + (A⋂B)|

|(A\B)| + |(A⋂B)| = |(B\A)| + |(A⋂B)|

|(A\B)| = |(B\A)|

---

If the above is true, then how does it apply to infinite sets and bijection? i.e. it's cited that
|***N***| = |***E***| for cardinality of natural numbers and even numbers.

So if we assume |***N***| = |***E***|, then

|***O***  +  ***E***| = |{}  +  ***E***|

|***O***| + |***E***| = |{}| + |***E***|

|***O***| = |{}|

No.  Why not?

Comment: The 3rd one does not hold for infinite  sets. We can have $A\supsetneqq B$ and $|A|=|B|$, so $|A\setminus B|\ne 0=|B\setminus A|$. E.g. $A=\Bbb N$ and $B=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: $$\color{red}{\Large\textbf{Cardinals are not real numbers.}}$$

Answer (score 5):

Your first and second equations are correct: the third is only necessarily true for finite sets.

The thing is, you cannot subtract infinite cardinals. If $C,D$ are two sets of infinite cardinality, then: $$|C|+|D|=\max(|C|,|D|)$$
Or so I am told. In your situation, $|A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|=|B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|$ does not imply $|A\cap B|$ can be validly cancelled from both sides: the maximum function can’t be inverted like that!

In particular: $$|O|+|E|=0+|E|$$Is true. $|O|=0$ is false, and the flaw in the logic is that you can’t ‘add $-|E|$ to both sides’.

Answer (score 1):

The [cancellation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) does not hold for cardinal addition.  The sum of two equal infinite cardinals is the same as one of them.

Comment: From your link:  "The positive (equally non-negative) integers form a cancellative semigroup under addition. The non-negative integers form a cancellative monoid under addition.

In fact, any free semigroup or monoid obeys the cancellative law, and in general, any semigroup or monoid embedding into a group (as the above examples clearly do) will obey the cancellative law."

Comment: @ShawnBob So what? Infinite cardinal addition is not free and doesn't embed into a group, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: Are the first two sentences correct? "The positive (equally non-negative) integers form a cancellative semigroup under addition. The non-negative integers form a cancellative monoid under addition."?